# subdomain per branch/namespace on K8S

Tags: kubernetes, subdomain, branch, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

Hi i have a question when it comes to k8s and handling branches

my namespaces have the following :

- an API deployment
- a `NodePort` service mapping the port `3000` of the deployment to port `80`
- a `postgres` instance to serve as a DB (Not important for this problem)
- an `Ingress` exposing all

I would like to find a way that would make it able to :

- When creating a new Branch, it makes my backend accessible to api.BRANCH_NAME.domain.com

I'm not able to find any documentation helping, I've tried a lot of things so far but cannot make it work

Here's a repo to see what I have so far : https://github.com/girards/tracks

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could deploy an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) such as nginx and create [ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to expose backend services using `host`.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-ingress-example
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.branchname.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: servicename
          servicePort: 3000
```

Comment: Thank you very much. any recommendation on the ingress controller to use ?